Error opening emulator even after creating a virtual device
I encounter an error opening the emulator in Android Studio. I have created an android virtual device but it is not getting connected to the android studio it is showing an error of Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\DHRUVA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.14.db, detection is enabled for process: 8592 INFO | Android emulator version 34.2.14.0 (build_id 11834374) (CL:N/A) INFO | Found systemPath
I have upgraded the SDK. From the project structure I have switched to Android. I am using the latest version of Android Studio and SDK of Android API 34, extension level 7 Platform.
